# Trying to access archives of a website Parser Error Message:

Tags: parsing

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'GenRegSys.Global'.

Source Error:

Line 1:  <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="GenRegSys.Global" Language="C#" %>

The website isn't mine

An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately

Comment: That appears to be an error on the website you're trying to access.